# Comparing values of columns with a list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have two columns in my dataframe, one with a number and one with a list of numbers. I want to create a third column True or False depending on whether the number in the first column exists in the first two elements of the corresponding list in the second column

Below is what I tried :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1, 2, 3], 'list_of_numbers': [[1, 3 ,2 ,5], [6 ,7 ,8 ,2 ,10], [13 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,3]]})
df['check'] = np.isin(df['number'], [x[0:2] for x in df['list_of_numbers']])
```

I was expecting and output of `[True, False, False]` but what I got is a `[True, False, True]`. I am guessing comparison is always being done against first value in `list_of_numbers` which is `[1, 3 ,2 ,5]` to get such an output.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a loop here:

```
df['check'] = [a in b[0:2] for a,b in zip(df['number'], df['list_of_numbers'])]
```

Output:

```
   number      list_of_numbers  check
0       1         [1, 3, 2, 5]   True
1       2     [6, 7, 8, 2, 10]  False
2       3  [13, 12, 13, 14, 3]  False
```

##### why your approach failed

`np.isin` flattens the test_element array before use, so you do not test each element against  each list, but rather against the concatenation of all lists

Demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1, 1, 3], # we changed the 2 in 1
                   'list_of_numbers': [[1, 7, 2, 5],  # we removed the 3
                                       [6, 7, 8, 2, 10],
                                       [13, 12, 13, 14, 3]]})

df['check'] = np.isin(df['number'], [x[0:2] for x in df['list_of_numbers']])
print(df)
   number      list_of_numbers  check
0       1         [1, 7, 2, 5]   True
1       1     [6, 7, 8, 2, 10]   True # we have True as the first list has a 1
2       3  [13, 12, 13, 14, 3]  False # now we have False as the 3 in the first list is gone
```

Comment: So are you saying `x[0:2]` has no effect in my code? Great answer btw. Your suggestion works fine. Thanks :) I'll accept the answer.

Comment: No, `[0:2]` has an effect, but the fact that you have multiple lists doesn't mean that each number will be paired with their list. They will all be checked against `list1[0:2]+list2[0:2]+list3[0:2]`